# How to merge columns in SQL of the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have two date columns.
Sometimes they both have dates(Which will be same always in both the columns) and sometimes one is empty and one has date value.
So, instead of two columns, I am trying to get one column.
If one is empty it will take date value from other column and if both have values(which will always be same) it will just take any of the value from the two columns.

I have tried UNION commands but its not giving me the desired result.

[image]

Comment: How have to use a CASE statement in your query

Comment: I didn't mean to copy the images into your question, Talha.  I meant put the `Create Table` statement in your question **as text**.  That way, the people helping you here don't have to transcribe the code - they can just copy/paste it.  See [ask] and [mcve] for further details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server has a couple different options for this scenario. You can use [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), or a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement.

Based on the information you provided I would use COALESCE. It offers several benefits over ISNULL and is very simple to implement. A CASE statement seems like overkill for what you are trying to do. Check out the link above for more info on each solution.

Comment: Example: `SELECT col1, col2, ..., COALESCE(date1, date2) AS date FROM tablename`

Comment: Thanks. that is something I was looking for

Comment: It helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You need [Coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Also, in the future, you should put sample data and metadata in text in your question, rather than as attachments.

Comment: Thanks. that is something I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ISNULL statement if it is SQL

```
SELECT  ISNULL(ReturnDate,RepartureDate) as dateAct FROM AviationReservation_dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET Date1Column = ISNULL(Date1Column, Date2Column);
```

Context: `ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )`, if first argument is not null, it will use that argument.

After the update, delete the other column.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no case for both column to be empty, then in such condition, you can do something like this:

```
 SELECT
       CASE
              WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN column2
              WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN column1
              ELSE column1 orcolumn2
```

Comment: Thanks. that is something I was looking for